cannot exit python with keyboard.add_hotkey
I am trying to add a hotkey to my python program so that I can quit out of it without having to click on the anaconda prompt and do ctrl+c.
From another topic I see that sys.exit() merely raises an exception, but when I run the below code and hit ctrl+q after the first 'Hello', the program does not stop until it has run in its entirety.
'hotkey' is printed when I do ctrl+q, even when the anaconda prompt is not the active window (success), but I can't seem to exit the program any way.
Thanks all in advance.
import time
import keyboard as kb
import sys

def on_hotkey():
    print('hotkey')
    quit()
    exit()
    sys.exit()
kb.add_hotkey('ctrl + q', on_hotkey )
for i in range(3):
    print('Hello')
    time.sleep(5)


Turns out I just needed to do a little more reading. os._exit(0) is what works.
import time
import keyboard as kb
import sys
import os

def on_hotkey():
    print('hotkey')
    os._exit(0)
    
kb.add_hotkey('ctrl + q', on_hotkey )
for i in range(3):
    print('Hello')
    time.sleep(5)

